# Is there a more efficient way to write code for bin values in Databricks SQL?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am using Databricks SQL, and want to understand if I can make my code lighter:

```
   Select
case when (
        age_18__24 is null AND
        age_25__34 is null AND
        age_35__44 is null AND
        age_45_or_more is null
      ) then 1 else 0 end as flag1...
```

Instead of writing each line, is there a cool way to state that all of these columns starting with "age_" need to be null in 1 or 2 lines of code?

Comment: What format is the data in? Is each age bucket a separate column?

Comment: @lesk_s yes, correct. Each age bin is its own column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each bin is a column then you probably are going to have to spell it out, but you could use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#coalesce):

```
select
  case when 
    coalesce(age_18__24, age_25__34, age_35__44, age_45_or_more) is null 
    then 1 else 0
  end as flag1
```